# Ruby on Rails application with passenger-4.0.41 / apache2 shuts down every couple of hours

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, apache2.4

i have a problem and not sure what is going on. I have a running and working ruby on rails application. I set it up via apache 2 and, the GEM passenger-4.0.41

Now... every couple of hours.. the site just shuts down. Afer that i have to restart apache and everything works fine again.

I am not getting any smarter by reading the error log (first lines in
 following):

> Raw process output:
>
> /home/ccs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/passenger-4.0.41/lib/phusion_passenger/preloader_shared_helpers.rb:100:in
>   `initialize': No such file or directory - connect(2) for
>   "/tmp/passenger.1.0.30914/generation-1/backends/preloader.11394"
>   (Errno::ENOENT)   from
>   /home/ccs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/passenger-4.0.41/lib/phusion_passenger/preloader_shared_helpers.rb:100:in`
>   new'     from
>   /home/ccs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/passenger-4.0.41/lib/phusion_passenger/preloader_shared_helpers.rb:100:in
>   `run_main_loop'   from
>   /home/ccs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/passenger-4.0.41/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:159:in`
>   '    from
>   /home/ccs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/passenger-4.0.41/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in
>   `<module:PhusionPassenger>'   from
>   /home/ccs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/passenger-4.0.41/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in`
>   '

Does anyone know why my system is doing this? Possible that the server is too slow and this is a time out issue of some kind? Any help apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some kind of /tmp cleaner daemon on your system is removing important Passenger runtime files, causing Passenger to malfunction. You should tell Passenger to use a directory that is not affected by /tmp cleaner daemons.

If I remember correctly, this is done on Passenger 4 as follows:

```
PassengerTempDir /some-path
```

On Passenger 5 (which you should really upgrade to), you should use [PassengerInstanceRegistryDir](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/apache/reference/#passengerinstanceregistrydir). See that option's documentation for more information.

Comment: Thanks - awesome answer. That makes sense! I ll try it out and give feedback tomorrow!